How to disable xdebug in EasyPHP'S Apache?
I searched StackOverflow and I disabled xdebug in EasyPHP's php.ini as suggested by SO answers. But it still replaces ionCube's line in php.ini with xdebug. I guess it is done by Apache and not by php as I disabled it. How to make EasyPHP stopping to change my custom php.ini in order to keep ionCube's zend_extension line in php.ini without being replaced with xdebug?
